# Кoнфликт parallax в Materialize CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, parallax, materialize-css

Делаю макет с Materialize CSS. Встроенный `parallax` не нравится, решил [кастомный делать](https://jsfiddle.net/e19wbnhs/) (рабочий вариант, не раз внедрял).

Не могу понять, внедряю сюда, появляется полоса (дублируется фон), пропадает, если убрать `fixed`, но так не работает сам `parallax`:

```
function Parallax() {
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop() + 1;
        $('.stat-slid-prlx').css('background-position', '15' + -(scrolled * 0.3) + 'px');
    }


    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        Parallax();
    });
```

[Мой блок.](http://wshellx.myjino.ru/energy/)

```
<div class="stat-slid-prlx " style="background: url(http://www.cok-rf.ru/img/first_level/4_p.jpg) fixed;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

изображение по размеру не подходит под фон и на большинстве экранов будет заполнять собой фон повторяясь. Лечить так:

```
.stat-slid-prlx{
    background-image: url(http://www.cok-rf.ru/img/first_level/4_p.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
}
```

Единственное - вам надо кастомизировать плагин так, что бы он ложил фон на блок не так - **`background: url(http://www.cok-rf.ru/img/first_level/4_p.jpg)`** fixed, а так - **`background-image: url(http://www.cok-rf.ru/img/first_level/4_p.jpg);`**

З.Ы. я так и не понял, при чём там параллакс. Там просто **`background-attachment: fixed;`**

Comment: Так он дублирует, я так пробовал.

Comment: Еще можно уточнить, Вы сказали `что бы он ложил фон` без `fixed`. Если я Вас правильно понял,это не в плагине,это в самом блоке приписано

Comment: @zkolya сейчас на сайте для блока .stat-slid-prlx генерируется стиль background: url(http://www.cok-rf.ru/img/first_level/4_p.jpg). Он явно динамический. А что бы расписать свойства фона подробнее, лучше использовать background-image вместо background. То, что изначально background: url(...) fixed, то = background-attachment: fixed. А предлагаю я отключить т.н. параллакс (его там по сути и нет, там обычный fixed для фона) и юзать натив css, как в ответе.

Comment: @zkolya я проверял ответ на сайте по ссылке - изображение набережной в этом случае растягивается на весь блок, но существенно теряет в качестве. Или вам и надо, что бы оно повторялось?

Comment: нет, как раз таки не нужно чтобы дублировалось. Если вот тут посмотреть http://cok-rf.ru/o_nezavisimoi_ocenke.php, например, все точно также и паралакс отлично работает как надо

Comment: @zkolya на сайте по ссылке, при прокрутке как раз хватает выcоты изображения. Мне кажется вы не поняли принцип fixed. при фиксед фоне получается эффект, словно целевой блок - это как бы окно, а за ним неподвижная картинка. И вот вы скролите сайт, окно скролится то же. А если высота картинки меньше высоты экрана, то она заполняет оставшуюся пустоту свой копией. Поэтому либо растягивайте существующее изображение, либо используйте при фиксед фоне изображение примерно равное разрешению экрана (а лучше с запасом), если скролить придётся через всю высоту экрана.

Comment: cok-rf.ru/o_nezavisimoi_ocenke.php - а тут-то как раз скролить можно только вверх и высоты изображения фона хватает.

Comment: @ Kirill Korushkin, Да, Вы правы. Я не до конца понял, действительно и на том сайте так. Нужно большую картинку брать или растягивать. Спасибо Вам большое